# moving javascript into assets folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

im trying to move my javascipt from the view page, where it works, into the assets/javascripts file. However when i make the move, the javascript no longer executes. Im not sure why?

```html
$('.dropbtn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active") ) {
      $(this).parent(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  else{
  $('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show');
  $(this).parent(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-content').addClass('show');
  $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd assume it's because it's not being included on the page any more. So, I don't think we need your JavaScript code here - if it worked *before* the move but not *after*, then the JS code isn't at fault - it's the move that broke it and we have to figure out why the files aren't being included properly.

Comment: You are using javascript directly in `html` without using `<script>` tag

Comment: @MaheerAli no im not. Ive moved it into its own .js file, but its still not working

Comment: @VLAZ any suggestions?

Comment: @b.herring none without knowing how the files should be included. And since I don't really know enough about how Rails builds and bundles everything, I doubt I can help. But other ROR developers probably could - I assume they'd need details to do with how your files are being included. It's been too long since I've done my tiny amount of Ruby on Rails development, so I can't remember what this would be. But it should be something excerpt of the config files for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Javascript file is included in the asset pipeline it will be concatenated, minified and preprocessed into one big .js file that is included -by default- in your layout's `<head>`. By the time the browser is reading this file, the dom element associated with the `.dropbtn` class hasn't loaded yet, so the `click` event listener never gets added.

The solution would be to wrap your code inside a function that gets called once the document has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code goes here.
});
```

However, if you're using turbolinks (which is included by default in rails) you need to use:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  // your code goes here.
});
```

The reason for this is that once the document is loaded, turbolinks will update it instead of reloading it after each request, so `$(document).ready()` will only fire once while `'turbolinks:load'` will fire every time there's content loaded by turbolinks in your app.

Comment: thanks for your answer. There seems to a syntax error when i add your code to mine. It highlights the last `));` of your code in pink. Ive tried removing things but cant fix.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I missed the brackets, but I updated the answer!